# Loading Javascript file when module load

Tags: module, javascript, xml

I am developing custom Module in Magento 1. Now I would like to load my module specific JS file when then module enabled. In this regard I used below xml code in a separate xml file named as module name which is placed inside layout folder. My module don't have any controller.

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs">
            <js>brand_logo.js</js> 
        </action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

But the JS file is not loading at the time of module loading.

How can I do that??

Answer (score 0):

try `ifconfig`

```
<action method="addItem" ifconfig="my_config_section/general/enabeld"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/my_module/my_module.js</name></action>
```

Comment: @Qaiser Satti, Thanks for your reply. My module name is **brand_logo**. I placed a file in layout folder name **brand_logo.xml**. My requirement is when my module will be loaded then js file also be loaded. Thanks